# Intelligent Image Cropping

Tags: php, image

I'm a bit stuck on trying to explain to a customer of my theme that cropping of an image by intelligently figuring out the sweet and right spot is not an easy task at all. I'm even doubtful if that is 100% possible at all.

Say, in a Portrait, if an image is to be cropped as a square or a proportion, will it be possible to focus on the face and do the cropping accordingly.

Here is the question in question, if you wish to know more details
http://getsatisfaction.com/autochrome/topics/portrait_image_thumbnail

Comment: Is it not possible for the user to choose where to crop the image?

Answer (score 2):

You can try ImageKit.io. It provides [smart cropping](https://imagekit.io/blog/smart-crop-intelligent-image-cropping-imagekit/) out of the box. It uses face and feature detection internally to make the necessary computations for smart crop. ImageKit also has a face-crop mode that picks out the face from the original image to create a thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the problem your customer is having, is one of aspect ratio.

You very much can determine the source aspect ratio and crop/adjust from there.  Just use `getImageGeometery()`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagegeometry.php

Or, if using GD:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 1):

The "right" place to crop an image is subjective. Determining what is important to the scene composition is as much art as science. If a computer algorithm could figure this out perfectly, you could use it (and a large number of cameras spread across the world) to win the National Geographic photo contest every year :-).

That said, if you can more precisely define the parts of the image which are of interest - such as the faces you mention - then the problem moves from "almost-literally impossible" to "very difficult". You can use a face-detection algorithm and then crop to the smallest bounding box containing all the faces.

Answer (score 1):

(Hopefully you'd have found a solution already as this is a very old question.) I've found few options that help:

- [Cloudinary API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#automatic_cropping) - It supports few advanced cropping methods like automatic cropping and cropping based on face detection. I'm currently exploring this for a hobby project.
- [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/crop-hints) - I think this would be an overkill but you can use it for cropping portraits as it has good face detection and shows crop hints. I've used this for hobby project and works really well.
- [Grafika](https://kosinix.github.io/grafika/smart-crop.html) - This new Graphics library for PHP boasts of smart cropping where it detects the important region of the image and makes sure it is preserved while cropping (haven't tried myself yet)

Comment: Try out ImageKit.io for smart cropping as well. Similar to Cloudinary.

Answer (score 0):

A popular solution is to resize and center the image and crop what ever is left over: left and right if the original is too wide, or top and bottom if it's too tall. It's far from perfect for the reasons already mentioned, but easy to automate.

Sample code for doing it with the gd library in this gist: https://gist.github.com/1695782

Answer (score -1):

Have the user select the portion of the photo they want to crop. Add the offset to GD's cropping params. Good Luck!